# Strange sed behaviour

Tags: regex, shell, sed, posix

I have this POSIX compliant shell script. It takes a delimited string w.r.t. `|` and prepends a `-` to substrings if they are a single character in length:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '%s\n' "k|k|jill|hill|k" | sed 's/\([|]\|^\)\([[:alnum:]]\)\([|]\|$\)/\1-\2\3/g'
```

This outputs:

```
-k|k|jill|hill|-k
```

Notice it doesn't account for the k sandwiched between two delimiters (I.e., `|k|`).

Even more strangely, if I change the special characters in the original snippet to anything else, it does prepend a `-` (note the changes: `^` to `something`; `$` to `different`), but obviously not to the first and last k's:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '%s\n' "k|k|jill|hill|k" | sed 's/\([|]\|something\)\([[:alnum:]]\)\([|]\|different\)/\1-\2\3/g'
```

Outputs:

```
k|-k|jill|hill|k
```

At first I thought that it was because the `$` and `^` positional characters weren't optional. However they obviously are optional for `$` in the first flag and `^` in the last flag of the first example.

I'm very curious to know, why is this not working and can I do what I want to with a similar sed expression?

Comment: It doesn't account for `k` sandwiched 'cause it consumed first character `|` from previous match. So nothing to match again.

Comment: @revo could you expand upon that in an answer? Maybe demonstrate the steps that lead up to it failing? I don't fully understand your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if you change the sed script from a global search and replace to a loop, you can get your desired output:

```
printf '%s\n' "k|k|jill|hill|k" | sed 's/\([|]\|^\)\([[:alnum:]]\)\([|]\|$\)/\1-\2\3/g'
```

```
-k|k|jill|hill|-k
```

versus

```
printf '%s\n' "k|k|jill|hill|k" | sed '
    :a
    s/\([|]\|^\)\([[:alnum:]]\)\([|]\|$\)/\1-\2\3/
    ta
'
```

```
-k|-k|jill|hill|-k
```

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Programming-Commands.html

Comment: `sed` always seemed to me a terrible monster. Read page you referred to but still don't get how this looping works in this context. Would you mind explaining? +1

Comment: Man that is absolutely horrifying. Thanks for the remarkable answer!

Comment: @revo I think it works like a goto; a is the label of the goto, and ta is calling the function t, which goes back to the labelled goto. So ya goes back to a, looping. Not sure how it doesn't rematch that first pattern though. Sed is a black box

Comment: The `t` command branches only if the previous `s` command actually did a replacement. This example is basically a while loop

Answer (score 3):

Engine can't match `k` in middle since it had a previous successful match that its characters (`k|`) are consumed right before it and it can't fall into matching another `|`. Saying that if your input string was:

```
kk|k|jill|hill|k
```

you would have seen a desired output. For a workaround I'd suggest you to set `-r` option in order to enable ERE syntax to use a word boundary token:

```
printf '%s\n' "k|k|jill|hill|k" | sed -r 's/\b([[:alnum:]])(\||$)/-\1\2/g'
```

or more generally:

```
printf '%s\n' "k|k|jill|hill|k" | sed -r 's/\b[[:alnum:]]\b/-\0/g'
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! Any suggestions on how to do it in a POSIX compliant way? ERE is something I can't use in this situation

Comment: Please check out @glenn's perfect answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Learnt a lot about sed from this :)